# Почему-то не хочет возводить в степень

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus");
    int a;
    cout <<"Введите число " <<endl;
    cin>>a;
    if(a/10000<10) {
                   cout<<a;}
    if(a/10000>10){ 
                     int k(0);
                     int c=a;
                     while (c > 0)
                     {c=c/10;
                      k=k+1;}
    int b;
    b=k-5;
   b=pow(10,b);
   a=a/b;
   cout<<a;}
   if(a/10000=0)
   {                 int k(0);
                     int c=a;
                     while (c > 0)
                     {c=c/10;
                      k=k+1;}
   k=5-k;
   while(k!=5){ cout<<"0";
   k=k+1;}
   cout<<a;}
   system("pause");}
```

Comment: Можно понятнее? Что вы хотите получить, какой алгоритм используете?...

Comment: Ввести число. Если количество его разрядов меньше пяти, то вывести его на экран, дописав нули перед числом так, чтобы в итоге получилось пять знаков. Если количество разрядов больше пяти, то вывести только первые пять разрядов. Если число пятизначное, то вывести его как есть.

Answer (score 0):

Продраться через ваш исходник что-то не получается... не хотите по-простому, без наворотов:

```
string five(unsigned int val)
{
    string s = to_string(val);
    if (s.length() < 5)
        s = string(5-s.length(),'0') + s;
    else
        s = s.substr(0,5);
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    cout << five(15) << endl;
    cout << five(15621) << endl;
    cout << five(1535462) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Модифицировал ваш исходник и прошу прощения за то, что взял на себя смелость переформатировать его. Вот:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int a;
    cout << "Введите число " << endl;
    cin >> a;

    if ((a / 10000 > 0) && (a / 10000 < 10)) {
        // Выводим без изменений
        cout << a << endl;
    }

    if (a / 10000 > 10) {
        int k(0);
        int c = a;
        while (c > 0) {
            c = c / 10;
            k = k + 1;
        }
        int b;
        b = k - 5;
        b = pow(10, b);
        a = a / b;
        // Выводим первые 5 разрядов
        cout << a << endl;
    }

    if (a / 10000 == 0) {
        int k(0);
        int c = a;
        while (c > 0) {
            c = c / 10;
            k = k + 1;
        }
        k = 5 - k;
        // Выводим с предшествующими нулями
        while (k) {
            cout << "0";
            k--;
        }
        cout << a << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

А теперь давайте разберем все по порядку.

1. Следует учитывать, что выражение:

   ```
   a / 10000 < 10
   ```

   будет верно и в случае, **когда разрядов числа будет** `< 5`, ведь деление такого числа на `10000` тоже вернет `0`. Поэтому заменяем на комплексное условие:

   ```
   (a / 10000 > 0) && (a / 10000 < 10)
   ```

   (Скобочки для наглядности).
2. Со вторым условием, где

   ```
   a / 10000 > 10
   ```

   У вас все в порядке, да. Лишь добавил комментарий.
3. Третье условие:

   ```
   a / 10000 = 0
   ```

   Не видите ничего странного? Тут у вас **присвоение, а не сравнение**. Меняем знак на `==`:

   ```
   a / 10000 == 0
   ```

Но это еще не все. Если вы запустите свой алгоритм с числом `123`, то убедитесь, что вывод будет содержать `3` дополнительные нуля, а не `2`. Все из-за этого:

```
k = 5 - k;
while (k != 5) {
    cout << "0";
    k = k + 1;
}
```

`k` у вас **уже содержит количество нулей**, которые нужно дописать. А вы в итоге записываете нулей `5 - нужноеКоличество`. Так что либо убираете строку `k = 5 - k`, либо, как в моем примере, сравниваете `k` с нулем в условии цикла, и отнимаете от `k` единичку на каждой итерации.

И да, в конце вывода (`cout << a`) я добавил `endl`, дабы осуществлялся перевод на новую строку, а иначе в консоли может быть что-то неприятное вроде:

```
00123Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

И еще. Вы можете писать не 3 отдельные условия, а объединить их так:

```
if (...) {

} else if (...) {

} else if (...) {

}
```

А в вашем случае вообще:

```
if (...) {

} else if (...) {

} else {

}
```

(Т.к. существует лишь 3 возможных варианта - `числоРазрядов > 5`, `< 5` и `== 5`).

Таким образом, если сработает первое условие, то не будет необходимости проверять два остальных.

И да. Когда захотите сделать меньше дублированного кода и в целом сократить его, то вот пример такой реализации:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int a;
    cout << "Введите число " << endl;
    cin >> a;

    const int digitsToOutput = 5;

    int numDigits = 0;
    int c = a;
    while (c > 0) {
        c /= 10;
        numDigits++;
    }

    if (numDigits > digitsToOutput) {
        // Выводим первые 5 разрядов
        cout << (a / (int)pow(10, numDigits - digitsToOutput)) << endl;
    } else if (numDigits < digitsToOutput) {
        // Выводим с предшествующими нулями
        int k = 0;
        while (k < digitsToOutput - numDigits) {
            cout << '0';
            k++;
        }
        cout << a << endl;
    } else {
        // Выводим как есть
        cout << a << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Можно заметить, что я вынес `5` в константу `digitsToOutput`, и изменив ее вы можете изменить количество разрядов, которые будут выводится.